# Reduce the matrix and find the conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to do this question:

Reduce the system of equations to row echelon form to determine:

$$ x +  y -  z = 1$$
$$2x + 3y + cz = 3$$
 $$x + cy + 3z = 2$$

-c, if possible, so that there is a unique solution

-c. if possible, so that the system is inconsistent

-c, if possible, so that the system has infinitely many solutions.

I've tried reducing it, but I haven't been successful, maybe I don't know where to stop or how to determine c for each part.

Comment: **Hints:** Find the RREF as $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{c+3} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{c+3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ and the determinant as $$-(c-2) (c+3)$$ Can you proceed?

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your comment. And I think for the system to have a unique solution c = -3 and to have many solutions c != 3 and there's no c that would make this inconsistent? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

For Cramer theorem the system has one and only one solution when the determinant od the coefficients is not zero

$$
\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
  1&1&{ - 1} \\ 
  2&3&c \\ 
  1&c&3 
\end{array}} \right|=-c^2-c+6=-(c-2) (c+3)\ne 0
$$

one and only one solution if $c\ne 2;\;c\ne -3$

if $c=-3$

$$
\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
  1&1&{ - 1} \\ 
  2&3&-3 \\ 
  1&-3&3 
\end{array}} \right|
\;\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
  1 \\ 
  3 \\ 
  2 
\end{array}$$
the system is incompatible, inconsistent. The rank of the augmented matrix is $3$ while the rank of the matrix of coefficients is $2$.

if $c=2$ the system is indeterminate: has infinite solutions. The rank of the matrix of the coefficients is $2$ as the rank of the augmented matrix.

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
  1&1&{ - 1} \\ 
  2&3&2 \\ 
  1&2&3 
\end{array}} \right|\;\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
  1 \\ 
  3 \\ 
  2 
\end{array}$$

We can solve the system assuming that one unknown is a parameter
$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  y - z = 1 -x\hfill \\
  3y + 2z = 3 -2x\hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
Multiply the first equation by $2$ and add the second
$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  2y - 2z = 2 -2x\hfill \\
  3y + 2z = 3 -2x\hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

$5y=5-4x\to y = 1-\dfrac{4}{5}\,x$

$z=\dfrac{x}{5}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta=1\cdot3\cdot3+1\cdot1\cdot{c}+2\cdot{c}\cdot(-1)-1\cdot3\cdot(-1)-1\cdot{c}\cdot{c}-3\cdot2\cdot1=-c^2-c+6,$$
$$\Delta_x=1\cdot3\cdot3+1\cdot2\cdot{c}+3\cdot{c}\cdot(-1)-2\cdot3\cdot(-1)-1\cdot{c}\cdot{c}-3\cdot3\cdot1=-c^2-c+6,$$
$$\Delta_y=1\cdot3\cdot3+1\cdot1\cdot{c}+2\cdot{2}\cdot(-1)-1\cdot3\cdot(-1)-1\cdot{2}\cdot{c}-3\cdot2\cdot1=-c+2$$ and
$$\Delta_z=1\cdot3\cdot2+1\cdot2\cdot{c}+1\cdot{1}\cdot3-1\cdot3\cdot1-1\cdot{c}\cdot3-2\cdot2\cdot1=-c+2.$$
Now, if $\Delta\neq0$, which is $c\neq2$ and $c\neq-3$ then we get unique solution:
$$\left\{\left(1,\frac{1}{c+3},\frac{1}{c+3}\right)\right\};$$
If $c=2$ then our system it's 
$$x+y-z=1,$$ $$2x+3y+2z=3$$ and $$x+2y+3z=2$$ or $$x+y=1+z,$$ $$x+2y=2-3z$$ or
$$x=5z,$$
$$y=1-4z,$$
which says that our system has infinitely many solutions:
$$\left\{(5z,1-4z,z)|z\in\mathbb R\right\}$$ 
and if $c=-3$ then our system has no solutions.

Done!